# Silex FormServiceProvider and form.secret parameter

Tags: php, silex

I am using the `FormServiceProvider` from Silex and reading through the [documentation](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/providers/form.html) it explains how it has one parameter called `form.secret` which I assumed meant constructing the provider with this:

```
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\FormServiceProvider(), [
    'form.secret' => 'SECRET HERE'
]);
```

The problem is however when I look through the source code for this file I cannot see a constructor where this parameter would get used. Only seeing it set internally within the container to `md5(__DIR__)`.

https://github.com/silexphp/Silex/blob/master/src/Silex/Provider/FormServiceProvider.php#L48

Or would it be simply a case of not providing `form.secret` when constructing and simply setting `$app['form.secret'] = 'SECRET HERE'` after the provider has been registered?

Am I right in this assumption or I am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see it being used in [line 100](https://github.com/silexphp/Silex/blob/master/src/Silex/Provider/FormServiceProvider.php#L100), when `$app["form.csrf_provider"]` is first accessed:

```
$app['form.csrf_provider'] = function ($app) {
    if (isset($app['session'])) {
        return new SessionCsrfProvider($app['session'], $app['form.secret']);
    }

    return new DefaultCsrfProvider($app['form.secret']);
};
```

Since whatever you pass is ignored and overwritten with the md5 call you mention, correct usage would be:

```
$app->register(new FormServiceProvider());
$app["form.secret"] = "foo";
```